# Install4J: give feedback to user after successful JDBC connection check

Tags: java, jdbc, install4j

I'm trying to build the following form in Install4J 6.1.6:
[image]

After entering the host and a port number the user can check if these MySQL settings are correct by pressing the `Test connection` button.

The Host's variable is called `mysqlHost`
and the Port's variable is `mysqlPort`

I initially had a problem that the user entered input only gets saved to the variables when the `Next >` button is pressed, but I could solve this by adding
`formEnvironment.saveFormComponents()` to the `Key listener script` for both input fields.

I set up the following "Check JDBC connection" action for the `Test Connection` button:
[image]

And it works fine, when the host and port are set incorrectly the user will see a pop up with the error message.

However I'm not able to display a Success message or label when the JDBC connection works.
I tried adding a green Success label (as seen on the first picture) with the following visibility script:

```
String errorMessage = (String)context.getVariable("mysqlTestError");
return errorMessage.length() == 0;
```

So I'm trying to check if the `mysqlTestError` variable is empty or not.

But it's not working, the Success label is NEVER displayed.

How can it be only displayed when the connection check was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility script of the label form component is only evaluated when the screen is shown, so it will not update the visibility after the JDBC connection check.

You can update the label programmatically by adding a "Run script" action to the "Action list" of the button form component:

```
String errorMessage = (String)context.getVariable("mysqlTestError");
FormComponent formComponent = formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("ID of label");
formComponent.setVisible(!errorMessage.isEmpty());
((JLabel)formComponent.getConfigurationObject()).setText(errorMessage);

return true;
```

In install4j 6, the "formEnvironment" parameter is not available in action lists and you would have to get it via

```
FormEnvironment formEnvironment = ((FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById("ID of screen")).getFormEnvironment();
```